# How do you move table row to the top in Angular ngFor loop?

Tags: javascript, angular, sorting, ngfor

Using Angular 9, I'm looping through a list of data, but if a value equals `primary` I want to place that specific row at the top of the list or first.

I have the table working already and I'm looping using `*ngFor="let item of items | sort: sortColumn: sortAscending`. However, I'm struggling on the front-end to find the primary using `item.primary = true` and make it first in the loop, and then continue looping.

My Angular skills are limited here. I've seen the answer that `unshift()` will work, but I'm not sure how to code that into `*ngFor`.

NOTE: This is the standard `<table/>` table, not using `<mat-table/>`.

Hopefully, that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can "pre-process" your data before providing it to `ngFor`. Then `unshift` may come into picture to move the required row at the beginning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a pipe that make your element be at the start of the array.
First you create your pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
@Pipe({ name: "primary" })
export class PrimaryPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any[]): any[] {
    // get index of primary element
    const index = value.findIndex(el => el.primary);
    // get the element itself
    const primaryElement = value[index];
    // remove the element from the array
    value.splice(index, 1);
    // put the element at the start of the array
    value.unshift(primaryElement);
    / return the new arrary
    return value;
  }
}
```

Add your new pipe to app module in the declarations.
Now you can use this pipe in your component:

```
*ngFor="let item of items | sort: sortColumn: sortAscending | primary
```

Here is a live demo to help you out: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-component-pipes?file=src/app/app.module.ts)
In the live demo look at the following files:

- primary.pipe.ts
- primary-pipe.component.ts

Check the bottom of the html page for the preview

Comment: Worked like a charm. Inserted the code with no issues. Thanks for your help!